# Using Eclipse with sdkman! installed Groovy on OSX

Tags: eclipse, groovy, sdkman

I have installed Groovy 3.0.2 using sdkman! on OSX 10.13.6 and 'which groovy' reports /Users/adrian/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovy

But when I attempt to use Eclipse (2020-03 4.15.0) it won't pick up anything but the basic groovy packages - so hence code with imports like groovy.cli.commons.CliBuilder (the jar for that is in ~/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib) fail.

How do I fix this? (I can see no obvious way and I cannot even pick a directory name that begins with . in the IDE tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not use your sdkman install.  The [Groovy Development Tools](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki) supply their own Groovy libs.  For Groovy 2.5 and 3, that means groovy and groovy-test.  If you want additional modules, you can [add them to your ~/.groovy/lib directory](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Catalog-of-Features#classpath-container).  Or add Ivy, Maven or Gradle support to your project for more advanced dependency management.

Comment: Cheers - did this with a symbolic link